# Incorrect string value - Rails 4, ActiveRecord, MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encoding

Running an app on heroku and getting an activerecord statement invalid error when people try to enter text in for their bio in a textfield.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x83\x98\x09Fl...' for column 'bio'
```

Is there an easy way to solve this which doesn't require me to drop my db and re-create it?

Comment: Whenever someone enters a unicode char into the bio text field, I get a 500.  Is there an easy way to fix this on heroku?

Comment: I figured it out: Used this migration to connect to my production database and convert to UTF-8:  https://gist.github.com/bradherman/b0606ef2186b6b481ee1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/bradherman/b0606ef2186b6b481ee1

Migrated and fixed the issue.